# Get the field name that has a certain value

Tags: sql

I am currently making a simple program where you can view a record of a employees with an accountability to a certain department or not, but I am stuck on a sql code where you can view field(s) that has a true value 
(you are tagged 'true' if you have accountability)

```
select * from clearance where ? = True
```

is this correct format?

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: _Column_ name, not field name.

Comment: Not sure which DB you are using some DB boolean column consider as bit so you have to say `where columname=1` some cases 'true'

Comment: @soorapadman: a boolean is **not** a "bit" - at least no in standard SQL. If the column is indeed a `boolean` then `where column = true` is perfectly valid - actually `where column` would be exactly the same thing

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

The sintax should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE [columname];
```

Comment: yea i know, but i wanna see what are the field names that has a true value.

Comment: @Peter, if you should provide some sample data and expected outcome, it'll be easier.

Comment: @Zabi, your syntax should be `SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE [columname] = true; `

Comment: @DT Both should do the work, [columname] = 1 also should work, I only posted the easiest one for me.

Comment: @DT: if the column is defined as `boolean`, then `where the_column` is perfectly fine and is the same as `where the_column = true` (at least in standard SQL)

Comment: ＠Zabi & ＠a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks. I didn't know about that. This doesn't work on Oracle & SQL Server, right? I was able to get this works on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If it will literally have the text 'true' then the presumption is that it'd be:
select * from clearance where accountability = 'True'

If it is a bit (0 or 1), it'd be:
select * from clearance where accountability = 1

It'd be a lot easier to answer if you could advise the structure of the table you are pulling from.

Comment: `where the_column = true` is perfectly value (standard) SQL. In fact, if the column is defined as `boolean`, then `where the_column` would do exactly the same thing